# Bypass SonarQube naming convention rule for Application_ methods in Global.asax

Tags: sonarqube, global-asax, application-start

Is there any way to bypass the rule

```
"Rename this method to match the regular expression: [A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]++"
```

for the Global.asax.cs, specifically for the for the `Application_` methods/events? We don't want to minimize the amount of files that are skipped completely.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a narrow [exclusion pattern](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues) for this rule on this exact file, please follow instruction in SonarQube's manual.

Comment: Thanks! So as close as I can get is the file level, right? It is not possible to exclude specific patterns inside the file except ignoring them inline via using the ignoring start and end blocks.

Comment: Unfortunately Sonar does not accept my pattern(s). Ruley key pattern: squid:S00100 / File path pattern: **/Global.asax.cs. I also tried **/**/Global.asax.cs as a file pattern.